# Reflection method GetMethod does not return the static method of a class on an iphone, but does on simulator

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios

I have encountered a problem where the reflection method GetMethod is not returning a static method for a class. This is only going wrong on an actual iphone; on the simulator it is working correctly. I have tried the following:

```
MethodInfo methInfo = _type.GetMethod (methodName);
```

and

```
MethodInfo methInfo = _type.GetMethod (methodName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
```

but neither of these return the method specified in *methodName*. The specified method does exist as shown by the fact that it works on the simulator. I have confirmed with the debugger that my member variable _type does contain the correct class type reference. The methods that I am trying to retrieve are declared as public in the class.

Has anyone encountered this before or know why this would work on the simulator but not on the actual iphone?

Comment: The simulator and actual phone are very different. Differences like this do crop up. The MonoTouch forums is probably a better place to ask.

Comment: I was under the impression that the MonoTouch forums have move here; at least there was a message to that effect on the MonoTouch forums earlier in the year.

Comment: The MT team does monitor SO, and generally respond to most questions about MT.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reflection, although not fully operational on iOS, works. The problem is that the linker is activated on the configuration for the device and is cutting off the method since it is not being used. The linker cannot "see" reflection calls.

If it is a custom object, decorate it with the PreserveAttribute:

```
[Preserve(AllMembers=true)]
public class MyClass
{}
```

If it is an object from the SDK, you have two choices:

1. Disable the linker completely. This is not good since the final size will be big.
2. Use the method once in your code directly so that the linker will know it is there and will not strip it.

Comment: Thanks, Dimitris. You are spot on with this answer. The linker was indeed removing the methods. I added the _Preserve_ attribute that you mentioned and my application now runs correctly on the iphone. Thanks! :)

Comment: System.Reflection works just as well on iOS than on any other  architecture/OS supported by Mono. What's not supported is System.Reflection.Emit, which is a different beast entirely. Good advices otherwise :)

Comment: There are some issues with System.Reflection on iOS. Not all aspects of it work, most of it does.